# How to wrap text to next cell in tableview component?

Tags: javafx

I need to fill a text from database in cell, but when the cell is full, the text should continue in the next cell, down this.

I have one idea how implement it:

```
 Text theText = new Text(jFXTextFieldSearch.getText());
    theText.setFont(jFXTextFieldSearch.getFont());
    double width = theText.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
    System.out.println(width);
```

How good is this method, or is there another way to do it?
The database is large enough, and table has 50 pages.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide an example as described there ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@FXML
private TableView<String> table;

@FXML
private TableColumn<String, String> column;

...

String string =
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt " +
        "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco " +
        "laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in " +
        "voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat " +
        "non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

AttributedString attributedString = new AttributedString(string);
attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));

AttributedCharacterIterator iterator = attributedString.getIterator();
FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(new AffineTransform(), true, true);
LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(iterator, frc);

ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
while (measurer.getPosition() < iterator.getEndIndex()) {
    TextLayout layout = measurer.nextLayout((float) column.getWidth());
    list.add(string.substring(measurer.getPosition() - layout.getCharacterCount(), measurer.getPosition()));
}

table.setItems(list);
```

The font to be submit to the `attributedString` should be the same as that used for rendering in the desired column.